# H12 request timeout on grapheneDB Neo4j connection

Tags: node.js, heroku, neo4j, graphenedb

Needless to say I am new to both Heroku and GrapheneDB. I have a Nodejs app using Neo4j that runs fine on my local machine. I moved it to Heroku and used GrapheneDB to connect the neo4j DB to the app. When I run the app on Heroku I get a H12 Request timeout when I try to login which require the database access. The only change in my code is the following recommended by GrapheneDB:

```
var graphenedbURL = process.env.GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_URL;
var graphenedbUser = process.env.GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_USER;
var graphenedbPass = process.env.GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_PASSWORD;

var driver = neo4j.driver(graphenedbURL, neo4j.auth.basic(graphenedbUser, graphenedbPass));

//var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "xxxxx"));
```

where I added the first four lines and commented out the fifth line.
The non-DB functions of the app works fine but any attempt to connect to the db result in a H12. I am using Javascript with Neo4j 3.0.8 and papertail for logging. The following is the papertail log when I tried to register a user:

```
Feb 09 18:53:44 puppydog-dev-2017 heroku/router:  at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/users/registerowner" host=puppydog-dev-2017.herokuapp.com request_id=867c7bc5-2d61-4c82-8b42-87732b21d449 fwd="104.244.227.83" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
```

Can anyone shed some light on whats happening here?

Comment: I'm Alberto from GrapheneDB. The code you're using to connect to your GrapheneDB database looks correct. At first glance, the connection with your database doesn't seem to be the issue. A H12 timeout error is given by Heroku when your app take more than 30 seconds to complete the request (more info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout). Could you share what you're doing in `/users/registerowner` ? BTW, you are experiencing issues it might be more convenient to contact us via the heroku support channel.

Comment: @albertoperdomo /users/registerowner is a post to add a node to the DB...just a Match by email and a create unique if not not found.

Comment: How large is your dataset? What plan is this running on? Also, have you opened a support ticket?

Comment: This is a development environment with less than 1000 nodes running on the free plan and yes I did open a support ticket......nothing yet. The problem apparently is not the H12 but an ECONNRESET error  on the first read attempt which shutdown the DB resulting in the H12 in subsequent DB access attempts.

Comment: Hello Michael, I'm sorry to read that you are still experiencing issues. I'm aware that our engineering team is investigating the issue. I hope they find a resolution soon.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the H12 is as a result of the DB being shutdown by a reset from the GrapheneDb platform. All subsequent calls to the DB result in H12 since the DB is not available. The original problem that cause the DB to shutdown is still unknown.

Comment: Ok so Heroku suspect the cause of the disconnect/DB shutdown is a bug in their configuration of the env variables that assign the URL and the credentials.....it's now 7 days since Heroku trying to solve the problem...still waiting...will update when I get an answer.